# Proof of the limit of a sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

The questions is this.
Let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}sin(nx).$ Each $f_n$ is a differentiable function. Show that

(a) $\lim f_n(x)=0,\forall x \in R$

(b) but $\lim f'_n(x)$ need not exist [at $x=\pi$ for instance].

Proof of (a)

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$ Since $|sin(nx)| \leq |1|,$ $\forall n > N \Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{n}sin(nx)\right| \leq \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} = \epsilon.$

Can anyone explain how to prove (b)??

Comment: Try computing $f_n'(x)$ (the derivative is with respect to $x$) and see what happens at $x=\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'_n(x) = cos(nx)$ and cosine is an oscillating function.  Let $x = \pi$.  Then,
$$ f'n(\pi) = cos(n\pi) $$
but this sequence oscillates from 1 to -1 hence it cannot converge.  To prove it, you can show it's not a Cauchy sequence.

Consider 
$$| f_m(\pi) - f_n(\pi) | = |(-1)^m - (-1)^n|$$

For the sequence to be Cauchy there would have to be an N such that for all $n,m> N$ we can make this difference as small as we want.  Instead, let $\epsilon =1$.  Pick any $N$.  Then there will always exist an $m>N$ and $n>N$ such that m is odd and $n$ is even.  But then
$$|(-1)^m - (-1)^n| = |-1 - 1| = 2 > 1 = \epsilon$$ so the sequence is not Cauchy.